# Tag docker image after successful testing

Tags: docker, dockerhub

We have a Jenkins process that do the following process:

1. build our application
2. build a docker image
3. push it to private docker-hub
4. run script on another server that pull the image and run integration test on it

If everything complete successfully we'll like to tag the image that was just built as `verified` and we want to have this tag on only one image.

How can I implement the tagging of the most recently tested image with `verified` and remove the `verified` tag from the previous image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag can only point to a single image, so once you tag an image and push it, anything image previously being pointed to by that tag will no longer have that reference. So after you run your test, run a `docker tag my_image:x my_image:verified` and then `docker push my_image:verified`.